# How to set filecompleter for every command arguments in java jline ConsoleReader?

Tags: java, jline

I need to add file names completer for every command parameters.

```
ConsoleReader consoleReader = new ConsoleReader();
consoleReader.addCompleter(new FileNameCompleter());
consoleReader.addCompleter(new ArgumentCompleter(new FileNameCompleter()));
```

This only completes the first word (the command name). How should I add an argument completer?